# Problem with an equation in the context of black hole creation in high energy collisions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, calculus, physical-constants

I am reading an article about possible black hole creation in high-energy collisions.

There's an equation: $b  \le \sqrt{s}/ P^2$, where $b$ is the impact parameter of the collision, $\sqrt s$ its energy and $P$ the reduced Planck mass. Further, it is said that imposing $b \gt 1/P$ we find from that equation that for black hole to form we must ensure $s \gt P$.

Sure, I understand why the energy of the collision should be bigger than the Planck energy, but I don't get why are we imposing $b \gt 1/P$ and how do we then get  $s \gt P$ from the first equation
PS: we are working in natural units ($\hbar = c = 1$).
If someone could help.

Comment: Cite the article and provide the relevant Schwarzschild radii.

Comment: Sure, here's the DOI 10.1142/S0218271808012413 You can find those equations at page 6. But they don't mention the Schwarzchild radii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up some powers of *s* in your question. Remember to make everything dimensionally consistent!

The Compton wavelength of a particle, or energy fireball, is
$$\lambda \sim 1/\sqrt{s},
$$
while the Schwarzschild horizon  radius  is
$$
r\sim {\sqrt{s}\over M^2}.
$$
I have called the Planck mass *M*, instead of your *P*, for memorability. This mass is defined by the point at which the Compton wavelength equals the horizon  radius as it shrinks behind it and into its own black hole, with increasing energy.

You may use the [impact parameter *b*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10714-007-0468-5.pdf) to set the linear dimension of the cross section (~$\pi b^2$), so $b\sim 1/\sqrt{s}$ plays the role of *λ*; it starts our larger than 1/M, but the collision fireball shrinks with energy to hide behind its horizon,
$$
1/\sqrt{s} \sim b\leq r\sim {\sqrt{s}\over M^2} \leadsto \\
s> M^2.
$$